# How to call Animated() function along with other components in components attribute in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Creatable, components } from "react-select";
import Animated from "react-select/lib/animated";

const Option = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
    <Avatar size="50" text={props.label} url={props.image}/>
      <div>{props.value}</div>
      <div>{props.label}</div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};
class ReactSelect extends Component {
render(){
return(
    <Creatable
            isValidNewOption={this.handleValidation}
            value={val}
            components={{ Option: Option }}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            isMulti={true}
            styles={customStyles}
            closeMenuOnSelect={true}
            placeholder={"Add Email Ids"}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
          />
)}
}
```

I was unable to add "Animated()" in components attribute besides Options. What is the syntax to add more than one component while one being a component and other being a lib for animation.

I want something like `components = {{Option} && Animated()}` so that I can modify the Options component as well as getting the animation by clicking onIndicatorRemove.

Comment: It's working. components = {{Option} && Animated()} is working. I don't know what happened before.

Answer (score 0):

`components = {{Option} && Animated()}` is not working for me. It only applies the first item in the outer curly brackets. How is it working for you?

Here is my sandbox code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pk0xjnm73x